# rewrite url with parameter or pagination beyond certain value does not work

Tags: pagination, rewrite-rules

The following has been added using "generate_rewrite_rules", I have also tried using add_rewrite_rule:

```
'products/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/page/?([0-9]{1,3})/?$' => 'index.php?product_cat=$matches[1]&whofor=$matches[2]&reason=$matches[3]&paged=$matches[4]',
```

The following option works up till page 9:

```
products/gifts/son/party/page/1/
```

The following does not work

```
products/gifts/son/party/page/10/
products/gifts/son/party/page/1/?city=newyork
```

There are products up to 6 pages, thereafter it shows no matches found till page 9 but after 9 it directly takes me to "page not found". Similarly, if I add a parameter, to the page which was working, it takes me to "page not found".

Edit 1: the variables have also been added to query_vars.

Edit 2: Adding the actual code as requested in comments. The following is pasted in funtions.php

```
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'register_custom_query_vars' );
function register_custom_query_vars( $query_vars ){
    $query_vars[] = 'whofor';
    $query_vars[] = 'reason';
    $query_vars[] = 'city';
    $query_vars[] = 'stype';

    return $query_vars;
}
function custom_rewrite_basic( $wp_rewrite ) {
    $feed_rules = array(
          'products/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/page/?([0-9]{1,3})/?$' => 'index.php?product_cat=$matches[1]&whofor=$matches[2]&reason=$matches[3]&paged=$matches[4]',
          'products/(.+)/(.+)/page/?([0-9]{1,3})/?$' => 'index.php?product_cat=$matches[1]&whofor=$matches[2]&paged=$matches[3]',
          'products/(.+)/page/?([0-9]{1,3})/?$' => 'index.php?product_cat=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]',
          'products/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/?$' => 'index.php?product_cat=$matches[1]&whofor=$matches[2]&reason=$matches[3]',
          'products/(.+)/(.+)/?$' => 'index.php?product_cat=$matches[1]&whofor=$matches[2]'
    );

    $wp_rewrite->rules = $feed_rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
    return $wp_rewrite->rules;
}

add_filter( 'generate_rewrite_rules', 'custom_rewrite_basic' );
```

Comment: Could you add the code where you're actually creating the rewrite rules and query vars?

Comment: @bosco added the code!

Comment: @SantoshSKumar You could try and use [Query Monitor](https://en-au.wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/) to determine what it is doing

Comment: @adamj, not really helping.. I see that whenever SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS is zero it picks up 404 template. Also, is_404 is being picked up rather than is_archive() is_paged()  is_tax()

Comment: @SantoshSKumar  It's very likely one or more URLs are conflicting. I would recommend going through the debug process of eliminating all your custom URLs except for only 1 and then trying to go past page 9. If the issue still persists, I recommend grabbing a vanilla WordPress and trying it of that just to be on the safe side. I would also recommend chucking `define( 'SAVEQUERIES', true );` into your wp-config and analysing the whole query step-by-step: https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress#SAVEQUERIES

Comment: @adamj, have done that... excluded all but one url and the error exists! This clearly shows that there is no conflict. SAVEQUERIES has just too much of information to know where to start.

Comment: @SantoshSKumar If you expect something to happen – and it doesn't – then it's a conflict in expected results. Grab a vanilla copy of WordPress and dump your stuff in there to test it. Do not install any other plugins on the vanilla copy, because they maybe creating the conflict.